# Trying to render a template based on result from mongoose schema's findOne() method

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to use a task id generated in mongoDB to render a template which takes the task id as an input. I'm new to node and mongoDB so I apologize for any wrong terminologies. The findOne method below returns null for the data parameter in its callback function though the task id is populated in the url.

I have tried using exec() and chaining then() but the implementation does not result in data being populated. Also, the MongoDB version is 3.4.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/createTask', function(req, res) {
  var newTask = new Task();

  newTask.save(function( err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.render('error');
    } else {
      res.redirect('/task/' + data._id);
    }
  })
});

router.get('/task/:id', function(req, res) {
  if (req.params.id) {
    Task.findOne({_id: req.params.id}, function(err, data) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.render('error');
      }

      if (data) {
        res.render('task', {data: data});
      } else {
        res.render('error');
      }
    })
  } else {
    res.render('error');
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

This should render the task template with a simple h1 added to test but instead returns a blank page.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is _id is an ObjectID type field, which means you cannot do `task.findOne({ _id: req.params.id })` and get the document in the data argument of callback function.

Instead use the oId variable instead of req.params.id in task.findOne()

```
const mongo = require('mongodb');
const oId = new mongo.ObjectID(req.params.id);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I checked the field type in Robo 3T and it indeed is an ObjectID type. Another alternative which worked was adding the "return " statement before `Task.findOne({ _id: req.params.id })`.

Comment: @Ron could you please add an answer explain how using a return statement before Task.findOne() is an alternative to this? And also it would be very helpful for others if you could please mark this as the answer if you feel so, so it can be closed.